# How to pass PowerShell variables from remote to local session

Tags: powershell, variables, invoke-command

Is there a way with PowerShell to pass multiple variables from a single Invoke-Command remote session back to the local session?

Example (variables are not passed to local session here):

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock {
$a = "Variable 1"
$b = "Variable 2"
$c = "Variable 3"
}

Write-Output $a $b $c
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$output = Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock {
    $a = "Variable 1"
    $b = "Variable 2"
    $c = "Variable 3"
    return $a,$b,$c
}
```

so, to get some output, you need to produce some output, alternatively you can just do:

```
$a,$b,$c = Invoke-Command -ComputerName Server1 -ScriptBlock {
    $a = "Variable 1"
    $b = "Variable 2"
    $c = "Variable 3"
    $a,$b,$c
}
```